# Decimal keypad. Forcing point instead of comma in some regions

Tags: ios, xcode, uikeyboard

I'm using the decimal keypad to enter IP addresses, however I overlooked the fact that in Europe they use , instead of . as the decimal. This makes entering IP addresses impossible.

Is it possible to force the keypad to use a specific region eg.US or UK regardless of a users device settings?

Thanks

Comment: I have ended up doing one of the old school adding decimal point to keypad tutorials. If anyone know a way to force the region, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, because you risk trying to force a keyboard that the user has not enabled.  However, you can use a custom keyboard if you wish, or set the input accessory view of a view(which is a small view that is shown over the top of the keyboard)

Comment: Thanks. I've had to use a custom keyboard. I already use an input accessory and it's not really the best place for a decimal point.

Comment: Don't suppose you have the code for this custom keyboard?  I'm in need of the same solution.

Comment: There is no "code for the custom keyboard."  It is simply a view that goes on top of another view and has a bunch of buttons and corresponding methods.